# Overwrite default delay for File in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb

is there a possibilty in camel to overwrite the default delay value for file processing? 
http://camel.apache.org/file2.html => the default deleay is set to 500ms. So camel polls everey 500ms a directory. I want set this value different for all my routes globaly, and not overwrite on each route manually ... any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: The only way I can think of is to set your desired value as a variable somewhere and put that in each route. So set the value in a header and inject the value of the header in your file uri for the delay parameter.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot set it globally. But it can be a nice idea, so you are welcome to log a JIRA ticket

Comment: Good idea, I will do that. Is this the Jira portal under  https://issues.jboss.org  ?

Comment: You can log at upstream Apache Camel: http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL. However if you have a Red Hat Fuse subscription you can use the customer portal to have a ticket logged and prioritized for the JBoss Fuse product.